# List premises & accounts within time period

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, max, distinct

I need to pull data from our MS SQL Server database regarding Premises (i.e. houses) and the accounts (i.e. people) that have live there (or are still living there) and their service period at that premise.

There could be three types of cases that I have to account for:

1. The most basic case where a person moved in, started service and is still living there
2. The next case is someone who's moved in, had service for a time period, but then has moved out and is no longer living in the location
3. The last scenario is someone who moved in, had service, moved out (ended service) and then subsequently moved back in (think apartment living).

The last scenario is where I am having issues and need some help.

The database has fields in an account_service table that list "from" and "to" dates.  To show how that would look in the database, I will list the data corresponding to the three cases above:

```
     Premise#  - Account# -   From Date -   To Date --     (details on the data)
  1. 00125466,   146732,      2/2/2001,     NULL            (no to_date since still living there)
  2. 10085279,   180887,      6/12/1978,    1/15/2020       (moved in and moved out)
  3. 00005110,   **267110**,    10/15/2020, 12/14/2021   (live there from Oct. 2020 - Dec. 2021)
  3a.00005110,   273341,      12/14/2021,   12/09/2022     (live there from Dec. 2021 - Dec. 2022)
  3b.00005110,   **267110**,    12/09/2022, NULL         (moved in Dec. 2022 and still there now)
```

What complicates all this is that the account_service table lists ALL the services that a Premise has active during the account holder's time there.  This can be water, sewer, trash, etc.

I am also only interested in accounts that had (or have) service in the last three years.

My SQL looks like this: (looking at just the #3 scenario above)

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.servicelocation.propertynumber, dbo.account.accountnumber, dbo.accountservice.fromdate, dbo.accountservice.todate
FROM   dbo.account INNER JOIN
       dbo.accountservice ON dbo.account.account_id = dbo.accountservice.account_id INNER JOIN
       dbo.service ON dbo.accountservice.service_id = dbo.service.service_id INNER JOIN
       dbo.servicelocation ON dbo.service.servicelocation_id = dbo.servicelocation.servicelocation_id
WHERE  (dbo.servicelocation.propertynumber = '00005110') AND (dbo.accountservice.todate > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2021-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) OR
       (dbo.servicelocation.propertynumber = '00005110') AND (dbo.accountservice.todate IS NULL)
ORDER BY dbo.accountservice.fromdate DESC
```

The output from the SQL above look like this:

[image: SQL output:]

Ideally, I would like to have the first line followed by the fourth line and then the fifth line as the final line:

[image: Desired SQL output:]

For reference, the SQL view looks like this:

[image: SQL View:]

The data in the software looks like this:

[image: Data in software:]

I hope this explains fully what I am after, but please let me know if more information is needed.
Thank you!

[Edit - More Clarification]
Ideally, I would like the MIN(from_date) and MAX(to_date) for each premise and account.  That works when there is only one resident, but when we have several tennants moving in and out, it gets complicated fast.
My query will list the two accounts (for scenario #3), but will only show 267110 living there from Oct. 15, 2020 to the present time as they are still there.  This creates an issue because 273341 lived there DURING that time.  We can't  have two occupants/accounts at a Premise for the same time period.

I've tried various permutations on the view... using MAX(to_date) helps in certain cases, but misses the scenario #3 described earlier.
I think this is possible, but am having a tough time coming up with the correct SQL.

[image: Result Set:]

Comment: @BartMcEndree i understand you're eager to write some code, it's great, but the comments are not really supposed to be a work in progress or stream of concience, it's better if you work on the code and then post your answer or comment once, not partial steps. If something is unclear, it's better to ask the OP some questions before answering. Also, the answer should ideally be self-contained, because links can dissapear at any time, and people coming back to old answers can't follow the link

Comment: @OP, is there at least one period which covers the whole living time of the resident? Or does one have to stich potential living periods together?

Comment: @siggemannen partial step comments deleted.

Comment: @siggemannen, if there is a resident, then they were living there for *some* amount of time.  Usually it's just once (especially in the 3 year window), but there are cases like above where someone moves in, leaves and then comes back. Those are the ones that need to be stiched together.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

If we sort by [from date] and add a row counter that resets for each property+account we can identify individual occupation periods.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT propertynumber, dbo.account.accountnumber, dbo.accountservice.fromdate,dbo.accountservice.todate, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY dbo.servicelocation.propertynumber+dbo.account.accountnumber ORDER BY FromDate DESC) as OccupationSequence
FROM   dbo.account 
INNER JOIN  dbo.accountservice ON dbo.account.account_id = dbo.accountservice.account_id 
INNER JOIN  dbo.service ON dbo.accountservice.service_id = dbo.service.service_id 
INNER JOIN  dbo.servicelocation ON dbo.service.servicelocation_id = dbo.servicelocation.servicelocation_id
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Rk0g0eri)

| propertynumber | accountnumber | fromdate | todate | OccupationSequence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00005110 | **267110** | 2020-10-15 | 2021-12-14 | 2 |
| 00005110 | **267110** | 2022-12-09 | null | 1 |
| 00005110 | 273341 | 2021-12-14 | 2022-12-09 | 1 |

| propertynumber | accountnumber | MinFrom | MaxTo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00005110 | **267110** | 2022-12-09 | null |
| 00005110 | 273341 | 2021-12-14 | 2022-12-09 |
| 00005110 | **267110** | 2020-10-15 | 2021-12-14 |

Comment: thank you for this!  When I run on my data, I am getting more rows than I want (due to the number of services each property+account has...  
I will add in a screenshot to my post so you can see what I am talking about, I'd like to have just the bolded lines if possible.  The yellow highlighted rows are the tennants  I am interested in living there inside the three year window. Thank you

Comment: There is no difference between the bold and normal lines except Occupation Sequence.  So just include the query as a subquery and only SELECT propertynumber, accountnumber, fromdate, todate then use GROUP BY or DISTINCT to remove what now appears to be simple duplicates rows.